# Error when post JSON with image in base64 through RestTemplate on Android

Tags: java, android, json, spring, resttemplate

I searched a lot, but i don't found any solution. I am trying to post a json object with a image encoded in base64 to a web service via android, using the client `Resttemplate`.

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    ResponseEntity responseEntity;
    try {
        HttpHeaders header = createHeadersAthententicated(accessToken);
        header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json"));
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        jsonObject.addProperty("base64File", ImageUtil.bitmapToString(user.getProfileImageInBitmap()));
        jsonObject.addProperty("filename", "profileImage".concat("_").concat(user.getEmail()));
        HttpEntity<JsonObject> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject, header);
        responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(userUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } catch (RestClientException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, e1.getMessage(), e1);
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(e1.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }


public static String bitmapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return temp;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The error that I got:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write JSON: JsonObject (through reference chain:
>   com.google.gson.JsonObject["asBigDecimal"]); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject
>   (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asBigDecimal"])

Answer (score 0):

I don't made progress with Resttemplate, so i changed to OkHttp3

```
 final okhttp3.MediaType JSON = okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json");
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + accessToken)
            .url(userUrl)
            .post(body)
            .build();
```

Works perfect.

Just more one thing when you go convert to base64 you have to use Base64.NO_WRAP, this not put the break line.